# Regular expression in Beautiful Soup output

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the lines from html page, proccessed by BS, containing
word 'billion'. But I am getting empty list..... Btw, these lines are between
    `<li>` tags, I have tried to use `soup.findAll("<li>", {"class": "tabcontent"})`

but it gives me an empty list also.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'http://www.worldstopexports.com/united-states-top-10-exports/'

header = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"
}

page = requests.get (url, headers=header)

soup = BeautifulSoup (page.text, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all (class_='tabcontent')[0].text

print(re.findall(r'^.*? billion', table))

print(table)



Machinery including computers: US$201.7 billion (13% of total exports)
Electrical machinery, equipment: $174.2 billion (11.3%)
Mineral fuels including oil: $138 billion (8.9%)
Aircraft, spacecraft: $131.2 billion (8.5%)
Vehicles: $130.1 billion (8.4%)
Optical, technical, medical apparatus: $83.6 billion (5.4%)
Plastics, plastic articles: $61.5 billion (4%)
Gems, precious metals: $60.4 billion (3.9%)
Pharmaceuticals: $45.1 billion (2.9%)
Organic chemicals: $36.2 billion (2.3%)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `select()` to first get the tab and then the `li` children and the text:

```
# ... right under soup = BeautifulSoup (page.text, 'lxml') ...
# select the first tab
tab = soup.select('div.tabcontent')[0]

# select its items
items = [text 
    for item in tab.select('li') 
    for text in [item.text] 
    if "billion" in text]
print(items)
```

This yields

```
['Machinery including computers: US$201.7 billion (13% of total exports)', 'Electrical machinery, equipment: $174.2 billion (11.3%)', 'Mineral fuels including oil: $138 billion (8.9%)', 'Aircraft, spacecraft: $131.2 billion (8.5%)', 'Vehicles: $130.1 billion (8.4%)', 'Optical, technical, medical apparatus: $83.6 billion (5.4%)', 'Plastics, plastic articles: $61.5 billion (4%)', 'Gems, precious metals: $60.4 billion (3.9%)', 'Pharmaceuticals: $45.1 billion (2.9%)', 'Organic chemicals: $36.2 billion (2.3%)']
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error is in using `.*`; the dot operator doesn't normally match newlines, and the `table` string contains newlines between the start and the word *billion*. If you are going to use a regex, then at least use the `re.MULTILINE` flag to have the `^` match after newlines:

```
>>> re.findall(r'^.*billion', table, flags=re.MULTILINE)
['Machinery including computers: US$201.7 billion',
 'Electrical machinery, equipment: $174.2 billion',
 'Mineral fuels including oil: $138 billion',
 'Aircraft, spacecraft: $131.2 billion',
 'Vehicles: $130.1 billion',
 'Optical, technical, medical apparatus: $83.6 billion',
 'Plastics, plastic articles: $61.5 billion',
 'Gems, precious metals: $60.4 billion',
 'Pharmaceuticals: $45.1 billion',
 'Organic chemicals: $36.2 billion']
```

However, since you want to find the text in `li` elements, why not select on those?

```
soup.find(class_='tabcontent').find_all('li', string=re.compile(r'billion'))
```

Passing in a regular expression pattern to `string` lets you filter on the contents of the elements. This gives you the matching elements:

```
>>> soup.find(class_='tabcontent').find_all('li', string=re.compile(r'billion'))
[<li>Machinery including computers: US$201.7 billion (13% of total exports)</li>,
 <li>Electrical machinery, equipment: $174.2 billion (11.3%)</li>,
 <li>Mineral fuels including oil: $138 billion (8.9%)</li>,
 <li>Aircraft, spacecraft: $131.2 billion (8.5%)</li>,
 <li>Vehicles: $130.1 billion (8.4%)</li>,
 <li>Optical, technical, medical apparatus: $83.6 billion (5.4%)</li>,
 <li>Plastics, plastic articles: $61.5 billion (4%)</li>,
 <li>Gems, precious metals: $60.4 billion (3.9%)</li>,
 <li>Pharmaceuticals: $45.1 billion (2.9%)</li>,
 <li>Organic chemicals: $36.2 billion (2.3%)</li>]
```

You can always apply `.get_text()` to those elements if you only wanted their contents.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be something like below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'http://www.worldstopexports.com/united-states-top-10-exports/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL,headers={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0"}).text, 'lxml')
table = soup.find(class_='tabcontent')
data =  '\n'.join([item.text for item in table.find_all("li")])
print(data)
```

Output:

```
Machinery including computers: US$201.7 billion (13% of total exports)
Electrical machinery, equipment: $174.2 billion (11.3%)
Mineral fuels including oil: $138 billion (8.9%)
Aircraft, spacecraft: $131.2 billion (8.5%)
Vehicles: $130.1 billion (8.4%)
Optical, technical, medical apparatus: $83.6 billion (5.4%)
Plastics, plastic articles: $61.5 billion (4%)
Gems, precious metals: $60.4 billion (3.9%)
Pharmaceuticals: $45.1 billion (2.9%)
Organic chemicals: $36.2 billion (2.3%)
```